# 12V Mobile Power Setup -

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, solar-energy, music

I am looking for feedback and experienced insight as I'm new to this world.

I have a 12V 18Ah AGM battery connected to a 300W 110V pure sine wave inverter with the intention of running a 140W speaker and my MacBook Pro which will charge from the 60W USB-C port on the inverter. People have been bringing drum sets and electric guitars to the park here and I'm keen on bringing my bass guitar and/or running ableton in the middle of Piedmont Park, effectively having drums, bass, synths or any other VST.

I'd like to firm up some things since I've been learning as I go here figuring this out. Ultimately I'm wondering how long I can power my speaker and MacBook, although I'm adding a solar panel to the kit for a constant trickle charge throughout the day. But for now lets pretend I don't have the solar charger.

A few outstanding questions:

- At what point does a 12V AGM battery drop below 12V? Subsequently what's too low of a voltage to be using the battery?
- Is it steadfast the my amperage draw is simply watts per device divided by volts per? In my case this is (140W/110V= 1.23A for the speaker) + (60W/110V= .55A for the MacBook) totaling 1.78 amps total load. Using max 50% of my batteries total Ah's, I get 9Ah/1.78A= ~5 hours of battery-powered playtime. Is it really this simple?
- I have a voltmeter hooked up to the battery and was considering an ammeter to be sure of my consumption; but if the amps rule is steadfast, then what's the point?

I'm assuming by adding a solar panel into the mix I can prolong. Given the day is sunny and I'm meeting the panels sunlight requirements, how do I factor these numbers into the equation? Research tells me 25% of the battery's Ah rating is a good amps for charging. 25% of 18 is 4.5 so a 48 or 60 watt solar charger should be great for this? Any tips, advice, or confirmation on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your battery is 18Ah at 12v.  You are are going to be drawing about 10 times more current from the battery at 12v than you have calculated using 110v.  Then there are additional losses in the inverter.

Comment: The equipment will probably not continuously draw the maximum amount of power but considerably less. You should really try measuring its power consumption, ideally from the point of view of the battery. Charging with 25% of Ah rating is a good estimate, but you should really consult the battery’s datasheet and maybe invest in a battery monitor.

Comment: A randomly selected high quality 18 Ah AGM battery datasheet I found indicates that at 11.4A you can get 11.4 Ah out of the battery, giving you 136.8 W to work with for 1 hr.  Kiss 20% of that goodbye in inverter losses and you have about 109.44 W for 1 hr.  It would be worth investigating a 12V stereo and charger to avoid extra power conversions, and also to measure actual load while using your computer and amplifier as you expect, as it may be reasonably lower.  Line voltage equipment is sometimes designed less with efficiency in mind.  Some types of amplifier are also much more efficient.

Comment: No, the calculations are wrong. Even in ideal case the battery can provide 1A for 18h at 12V so that's 216 Wh.  If your load is 216W which includes inverter consumption, the battery can power it roughly for an hour at 18A. In practice much less, maybe half an hour. But on the other hand, your devices will not draw constantly 200W.

Comment: 25A will kill a 18Ah lead acid battery pretty fast.